# How to split a string in URL pattern for redirection using NGINX or .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

How to split a string from the URL pattern in .htaccess or NGinx?

**URL Pattern:**

```
domain.sample.com/test-1.2.1/dir/version.com/media/azybIVcgifgod.mp4
```

**Expected output should be like,**

```
opt/test/storage/versin.com/a/zy/bI/azybIVcgifgod.mp4
```

Here, I have to split the string **`azybIVcgifgod.mp4`** into **`a/zy/bI/azybIVcgifgod.mp4`**

Please help me out!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you made any attempt?

Answer (score 0):

Your question mentions `nginx` and Apache's `.htaccess` file. This answer is `nginx` specific`.

To map this URL:

```
http://example.com/foo/bar/media/abcdefghijklm.mp4
```

To a local file located here:

```
/path/to/storage/a/bc/de/abcdefghijklm.mp4
```

You could employ a regular expression [`location` block](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) or a [`rewrite...break`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) to extract the parts of the URI necessary to construct the real pathname.

In the example below, the `rewrite...break` is used to split the last element of the path into four captures:

```
location /foo/bar/media/ {
    root /path/to/storage;
    rewrite /((\w)(\w\w)(\w\w)[^/]+)$ /$2/$3/$4/$1 break;
}
```